# Checking for empty list in Haskell: Is (length list == 0) or (list == []) more efficient?

Tags: haskell, optimization

Say I want to check if a list is empty in a guard in Haskell there are two options:

1. `length list == 0`
2. `list == []`

Which of these two logical tests are more efficient? I'm inclined to say the empty list test because relies on more basic constructs rather than the prelude function `length` but I'm not sure.

Comment: 1 is linear in the length of the list (obviously) while 2 is constant time. But 2 has the pitfall of requiring an `Eq` constraint when you don't really need it. Check for an empty list with `null` or simply by pattern matching.

Comment: the issue is pattern matching doesn't work when you want to compare equality to other predefined lists

Comment: Also thank you and that makes a lot of sense. Would you be able to elaborate more on null?

Comment: Indeed if you are actually comparing for equality (and not just checking for emptyness) then `==` is the way to go. `null` takes constant time as well as `(== [])` but has no `Eq` constraint. Furthermore, on the latest few versions of GHC, `null` is generalized to work with any `Foldable`, so e.g. `null :: Maybe a -> Bool` returns true iff the input is `Nothing`.

Comment: @user2407038 This should be an answer.

Answer (score 26):

`length list == 0` needs to traverse the whole list to get its length, which means it is *O(n)*. `list == []` yields an `Eq` constraint on the element type. `null list` runs in constant time and has no typeclass constraints.

However, there is a neat trick to do something like `length list == 0` which has the advantage that it generalizes nicely to `length list1 == length list2` without going through the longer list: you can use [`genericLength`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:genericLength) with a sufficiently lazy representation of natural numbers so that comparison will only force traversing the shorter of the lists.

One example is to use [the `Natural` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numbers-3000.2.0.1/docs/Data-Number-Natural.html#t:Natural):

```
import Data.Number.Natural
import Data.List (genericLength)

nats :: [Int]
nats = iterate succ 0

areThereTenNats :: Bool
areThereTenNats = genericLength nats >= (10 :: Natural)
```

Comment: Any "sufficiently lazy representation of natural numbers" is going to vary between being inefficient and ridiculously inefficient.  Also, any alternative solution to the OP's problem is going to have to do at least exactly what `null` does.

Comment: @DerekElkins, the traditional implementation of addition by pattern matching on the first argument and being "parametric" in the second will work fine. Still, you have to read the `genericLength` source code, and the `+` implementation source code, to verify that. It's much more obviously correct to just use parametricity to view `forall a . [a]` as a natural number.

Comment: @dfeuer I guess I should have been clearer that for the "==0" case, while it won't be faster than `null` it won't be excessively inefficient.  For any other case it's a recipe for churning garbage and wasteful calculations for something that should be walking down two pointers in parallel requiring no allocation.  It does have the same asymptotic efficiency as pointer walking though. I just wanted to indicate that if you're worried about efficiency, switching to a "lazy natural" type is the exact opposite of what you should be doing. (I'm not saying that Cactus was saying it was.)

Comment: @dfeuer: How is a non-zero number (e.g. 1) represented as a `forall a. [a]`?

Comment: @Cactus, I meant `exists a . [a]`, or the various ways to do that with `forall`.

Answer (score 22):

You can check if your list is empty in constant time with `null list`, which returns a boolean.

```
Prelude> null []
True
Prelude> null [1]
False
Prelude> null ""
True
Prelude> null "Test"
False
```

Comment: Yes, but what does this answer add to [dfeuer's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36481943/745903)?

Comment: As a newbie, I upvoted this because it clearly showed how to use the `null` API.

Answer (score 13):

As others have indicated, the best way to check if a list is empty (and nothing more) is to use

```
null :: Foldable f => f a -> Bool
```

which can be used at type

```
null :: [a] -> Bool
```

If you want to check if a list is empty because you want to look at its elements otherwise, you generally should be using pattern matching instead:

```
f [] = something
f (x : xs) = something using x and/or xs
```

If you want to compare the lengths of two lists (and no more), the best way is usually something like

```
compareLength :: [a] -> [b] -> Ordering
compareLength [] [] = EQ
compareLength [] (_ : _) = LT
compareLength (_ : _) [] = GT
compareLength (_ : xs) (_ : ys) =
  compareLength xs ys
```

The best way to check how the length of a list compares to a certain number is

```
compareToLength :: Foldable f
                => f a -> Int -> Ordering
compareToLength = foldr go (compare 0) where
  go _ r n | n <= 0 = GT
           | otherwise = r $! n - 1
```

Comment: ``compareLength = compare `on` (() <$)`` is another option for comparing length if you want something more concise.

Comment: @semicolon, good point. You could even make that an answer. `compare (replicate n ()) (() <$ xs)` is also potentially useful that way. Neither of these is going to be quite as efficient as doing it by hand, but they won't be terrible either.